# OpenGL teapot not drawing correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rendering, vertices

I am having trouble rendering my teapot downloaded from http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/data/meshes.xml.

Since I didn't want to spend too much time parsing the .obj files, I just copied the vertex data (preceded by "v" in the object file) and pasted it into C++ code. However, my rendering does not come out correctly. I can see the general form of the teapot, but it seems very fragmented. Since I'm using the new openGL and have not done anything with lighting or shading, I would have expected just a black blob in the shape of a teapot.

Do you have an guesses as to why my teapot is turning out as such?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an index buffer in addition to the vertex buffer.
The faces in the file are preceded by "f"

Comment: Thanks for the response. How exactly would I use an index buffer?

Comment: The spec http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec gives some examples of how vertices are indexed. the vertices preceded by "v" are not in the right order and duplicates are removed. the indices preceded by "f" will give you the right order